# iOS - Embed video in app with my app User Interface

Tags: ios, animation, user-interface, media-player, movie

I am working on an app that can play some short animated clips. At this point my only option is to embed animated frames. It works just fine. But I am just wondering if there's another way to simply embed the animated files directly as a movie clip in order to avoid importing tons of frames. Perhaps it'd be better for image compression.

In that regards I am aware of these alternatives: the MediaPlayer Framework, MPMoviePlayerController presented here http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/mediaplayer-framework_mpmovieplayercontroller_ios4/ and also some other techniques showed here http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios

However this would mean using Apple's UI. I would like instead to create a more integrated experience that is using my own app UI.

Is there a library for that?

Comment: I advise you to read about AVPlayer and AVPlayerLayer. You can easily add video frame inside your view hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take Look at AVPlayer Class Reference 
 https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html. 
and AVPlayerLayer Class Reference
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerLayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html 
It has the ability to do what you need. You can aslo animate the layer just like other CALayers

Comment: Thanks, I could make this work. You had actually referred me to the Mac documentation page for AVPlayer so I was a bit lost. I could find the one for iOS so all is good now :-)